# How To Dismiss UIPopover At DidSelectRow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uipopovercontroller

I have this code to present a popover:

```
- (UIPopoverController *)favoritesPopover
{
    if (!favoritesPopover)
    {
        FavoritesViewController *fvc = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvc];
        [fvc release];
        favoritesPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
        [navController release];
        favoritesPopover.delegate = self;
    }
    return favoritesPopover;
}

- (IBAction)toggleFavorites:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.favoritesPopover.popoverVisible)
        [self.favoritesPopoverpresentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
    else
        [self.favoritesPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now when `didSelectRow` is called in `FavoritesViewController`, I want the popover to be dismissed.  I tried `[self dismissPopoverAnimated: YES];` but that isn't recognized.

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to be returning `booksmarksPopover` from this function? Also, where/how are you presenting the popover?

Comment: That was a typo, fixed now.  I am presenting this via a UIBarButtonItem, added more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the popoverController in your FavoritesViewController.  Setup a popoverController property in FavoritesViewController and then you should be able to dismiss it in the `didSelectRow` method.

Comment: I did `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;` and added `[self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];` but still not dismissing.

Comment: In your favoritesPopover method, your not setting that property.  Try  fvc.popoverController = favoritesPopover;

Comment: In the method you first asked your question with (favoritesPopover).  In that method, right after you initialize favoritesPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];, place  fvc.popoverController = favoritesPopover;.  You will also have to move [fvc release]; below it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Also, same problem when selecting a row from the master view of UISPlitViewControler when its in popover mode. Isn't it supposed to dismiss automatically? How can I fix it there?